# casting to int order of operations

Tags: java, casting, int, double

I'm having trouble understanding why the following two should have any difference:

```
double d = 251.2453;
System.out.println(d);
d = .01 * ((int) (d * 100));
System.out.println(d);
```

Output

> 251.2453
>   251.24

versus this following output from dividing by 100 rather than multiplying by .01 before the cast:

```
double d = 251.2453;
System.out.println(d);
d = ((int) (d * 100)) / 100;
System.out.println(d);
```

Output

> 251.2453
>   251.0

Comment: Because `100` is an `int` and `.01` is not.

Comment: dividing by 100 is an integer operation so the result is an `int`, multipying by 0.01 is a floating point opertion and the result is an `double`. Note: neither option is particaulry useful. I suggest doing `Math.floor(d * 100) / 100.0` which is less likely to overflow, and have less representation error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> d = .01 * ((int) (d * 100));

1. `d * 100` -> still `double` - `25124.53`
2. `(int) ...` -> now an `int` so rounded down - `25124`
3. `.01 * ( ...` -> now a `float` - `251.24`
4. `d =` - now a double again - `251.24`

> d = ((int) (d * 100)) / 100;

1. `d * 100` -> still `double` - `25124.53`
2. `(int) ...` -> now an `int` - `25124`
3. `... ) / 100` -> still an `int` - `251` <<--- Here's the cause!
4. `d =` - now a double again - `251.0`

Answer (score 3):

In the second case you divide an Integer by an Integer, so the result is an Integer, while in the first case you multiply by 0.1 and therefore cast to a floating point number.

Answer (score 2):

In the first code, notice that

```
(d * 100)
```

is enclosed within parentheses. Therefore, this operation is done first and the value returned is

```
251.2453 * 100 = 25124.53
```

and then the (int) of 25124.53 is returned, i.e., 25124.
Now, you get

```
.01 * 25124 = 251.24
```

---

In the second case, `d * 100` is again enclosed within parentheses, so the operation is done first, and then the (int) of that result is returned, i.e.:

```
(int) 25124.53 = 25124
```

Now, 25124 is `int` and so is `100`. Therefore, an **integer division** takes place which returns the value **after ignoring the fractional part**. So you get

```
25124 / 100 = 251
```

and that value is stored as `double` which finally becomes

```
251.0
```

### Q.E.D.

Answer (score 2):

In the first case when you do

```
d = .01 * ((int) (d * 100));
```

it's actually

```
.01* 25124 = 251.24
```

In the 2nd scenario

```
d = ((int) (d * 100)) / 100;
```

It's actually

```
d= ((int) 25124.53)/100 = 25124/100 = 251
(it's division of int by int equal to int)
```

Now when you print d it's output as 251.0